# JPA @Query Left join same entity

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having an issue with making my query use left joins

I have a custom entity like this:

```
public class Form{
  UserEntity currentUser;
  UserEntity prevUser;
  long id;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Now my @Query looks like this.

```
@Query(SELECT NEW com.package.forms.Form(room.cUser,room.pUser,room.id) FROM Room room
 LEFT JOIN room.cUser cuser LEFT JOIN room.pUser puser WHERE room.id = :id)
```

And the query on logs are converted something like this:

```
select room0_.c_user,room0_.p_user,room0.id FROM room room0_ left outer join user user1_ on room0_.c_user = user1_.id
inner join user user2_ inner join on room0_.p_user = user2_.id
```

This query gives me no results. However, when I paste the converted query in logs to sql server and change the inner join to left join I get the results. How do I make both entities use left join?

I cant use native query because I'm using select new here for my custom class.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT NEW com.package.forms.Form(cuser, puser, room.id)
```

instead of

```
SELECT NEW com.package.forms.Form(room.cUser,room.pUser,room.id)
```

I think you must use `alias` of joined entity if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just switched the order of my joins. I was not able to show it but I also have left joined other entity as well it was like this before.

```
    @Query(SELECT NEW com.package.forms.Form(room.group,room.cUser,room.pUser,room.id) FROM Room room 
LEFT JOIN room.group group LEFT JOIN room.cUser cuser LEFT JOIN room.pUser puser WHERE room.id = :id)
```

Then changed to this.

```
    @Query(SELECT NEW com.package.forms.Form(room.group,room.cUser,room.pUser,room.id) FROM Room room 
     LEFT JOIN room.cUser cuser LEFT JOIN room.pUser puser 
LEFT JOIN room.group groupWHERE room.id = :id)
```